# Clear out Chrome history from command line?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

Is it possible to clear out Chrome's history from the command line? I know that this history is also cached online, ideally it would be good to do this from the command line as well.

Answer (score 1):

The Google Chrome history files live in `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default`. If you really, really want to delete browsing history from the command line (why?), I think removing the history files in this directory with a command line command/script would be the only way to go like [this guy is doing](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/clear-privacy-ie-firefox-opera-chrome-safari/). , as Google Chrome does not provide any ready-made commands or command switches for deleting history according to [this list](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/).

However, please consider this excerpt from the README-file:

> Google Chrome settings and storage represent user-selected
>   preferences and information and MUST not be extracted, overwritten or
>   modified except through Google Chrome defined APIs.

So, do it at your own risk. I would experiment with deleting the history files of a test installation of Google Chrome and see what happens.

Comment: I too need this, as often i have to clear chrome history to load latest code while doing web-development.

Answer (score 0):

To delete the files containing the all-time history (past 10 weeks) and the current (logged) history, do:

> cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default

then

> rm History History-journal